# Correlation between Ordered Variable and Categorical Variable

Tags: r, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, ordinal-data, polychoric

I am analyzing Opportunities for Sales people.

I have a categorical variable which is Status:{Won,Lost} My dependent variable, and other Independent ordered variables like the stages of the opportunity:{Prospect,Qualify,Develop...} or Activity Count:{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

I have read to find relation between two categorical variables, ill use Chi Square test , and if its two ordinal variables Ill use Polychoric Test

What if I want to find relation between Categorical and Ordinal variables ? Relation between Status and Stages, What test should I use, and how to do it in R. Thanks

Comment: Wilcoxon-Mann Whitney test.

Comment: @user2974951 I edited my question to say that my dependent variable is Status{Won,Lost} and its not ordinal, can I still use the test?

Comment: If your DV is Status and your IV is Stages then you are looking at a logistic regression with ordinal IVs, have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101511/logistic-regression-and-ordinal-independent-variables or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195246/how-to-handle-ordinal-categorical-variable-as-independent-variable.