# Can logistic regression predictor variables be nominal?

Tags: regression, logistic, ordinal-data, predictor

Can logistic regression predictor variables be nominal (like the charlson comorbidity index which ranges from 0-6)?

Comment: I wonder what you mean by an "ordinal" predictor and how that might differ from a categorical predictor.  Are you perhaps trying to ask about some form of [monotonic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=monotonic+regression)?

Answer (score 3):

First, the Charlson comorbidity index is not nominal, it is ordinal.  Indeed, if you use the [calculator](https://www.mdcalc.com/calc/3917/charlson-comorbidity-index-cci) from MdCalc that turns it into expectancy of living 10 more years, it could be thought of as interval, but that may not be what you want.

Second, yes, predictor variables can be nominal.

Third, ordinal variables are actually a bit trickier, but [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101511/logistic-regression-and-ordinal-independent-variables) offers some ideas and [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195246/how-to-handle-ordinal-categorical-variable-as-independent-variable) offers many more.

Comment: Oops, yes I misspoke - ordinal, not nominal. Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: Then please edit your question, and maybe add the tag [tag:ordinal-data]